# Django : how to use pattern searching?

Tags: python, django, testing, pattern-matching

Does someone of you know how the django's pattern searching is developed ?
using :

```
python manage.py test --pattern=test*
```

My tests are launched.

But when i try :

```
python manage.py test --pattern=[test]
```

I've no match

If you could enlight me :)

Comment: What if you use two `--pattern`s? Like `manage.py test --pattern='test_*' --pattern='foo_*'`?

Comment: Was a smart idea but the second pattern overrides the first one :/